# Usage of "be backed up"

Tags: meaning, usage, phrasal-verbs

I have a question about the sentence below

"I don't like when dirty dishes **get backed up** in the sink, so I do dishes right after eating."

According to the dictionaries(Longman, Britannica, Oxford, etc), it seems the phrasal verb 'back up' is used for traffic, toilet, sink, etc, not like 'dishes are piled up'

1. Do you think the sentence "I don't like when dirty dishes get backed up in the sink, so I do dishes right after eating." sounds natural? If so, would you let me know what dictionary has this usage?
2. "I don't like when dirty dishes get **piled** up in the sink, so I do dishes right after eating." sounds better to me. What do you think about this?

2-1) If "I don't like when dirty dishes get piled up in the sink, so I do dishes right after eating." sounds natural, then "I don't like when dirty dishes piles up in the sink, so I do dishes right after eating." sounds natural, too?

Comment: Think of "be backed up" here as "accumulation of chores due to procrastination or lethargy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries do not always provide exhaustive lists of all possible applications of a word. Things that should normally be dealt with promptly can be said to be 'backed up' if there has been delay or interruption in dealing with them, so that a queue has formed. One of the meanings of 'back up' (intransitive verb) is to accumulate in a congested state. Although the meanings you have so far found refer to interruptions in the flows of traffic, water, toilet waste, etc, it is common to use the verb generally about interruptions to any expected or required flow, such as the flow of dirty dishes, plates, cutlery, etc, from the sink in a kitchen, via the washing process, to their storage location once they are clean.

> you can help us stop calls backing up by reporting non-urgent matters
> online (my local police)
>
> I've got washing [laundry] backing up, dirty dishes in the sink. The
> lawn needs mowing (busy person)

Answer (score 1):

> According to the dictionaries(Longman, Britannica, Oxford, etc), it seems the phrasal verb 'back up' is used for traffic, toilet, sink, etc, not like 'dishes are piled up'

You are absolutely right, BUT:

It's common for words/phrasal combinations to be used *figuratively* as opposed to *literally*.  Figurative use expects you to not assume the literal meaning and think of how aspects of the original phrase might apply to the speaker/writer's expression.

Example:

> We went fishing for information.

There is not actually a lake, fishing line, fishing rod, etc.  However - when you fish - you sink a line in water and wait for something to bite, in places where fish are likely to bite.  So, these aspects are what the speaker/writer in this sentence would be expecting you to draw connections to.

> "I don't like when dirty dishes get backed up in the sink, so I do dishes right after eating."

Pipes can get clogged and no longer flow.  The speaker/writer is thinking of dishes in the context of "flowing" and doesn't want the flow to get clogged by too many dishes.  Perhaps the speaker/writer worked as a dishwasher where you definitely did not want your "flow" clogged.

Comment: A quick Google search showed that backed-up dishes are common where there is a broken dishwasher, lazy kitchen staff, busy person, etc.